# Extending end date then compare repeatedly

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

What I'd like to do is to extend `RxEndDates` until there is no more overlap in the prescriptions. And new extensions do not overlap either.

Context: If Amy takes Humera daily and gets a refill before her current prescription runs out, then add the DaySupply of the 2nd prescription to the first prescription.

```
sample data:
User Drug   RxStartDate DaySupply   RxEndDate
Amy Humera  2/12/2017   7   2/18/2017
Amy Humera  2/28/2017   5   3/4/2017 <--Overlap with below
Amy Humera  3/3/2017    5   3/7/2017 <--Overlap with above, need to combine
Amy Humera  3/8/2017    2   3/9/2017
Amy Humera  3/10/2017   7   3/16/2017
Amy Humera  3/17/2017   30  4/15/2017 <--Overlap with all below, combine
Amy Humera  3/22/2017   2   3/23/2017 <--Overlap
Amy Humera  3/24/2017   2   3/25/2017 <--Overlap
Amy Humera  3/31/2017   3   4/2/2017  <--Overlap
Amy Humera  4/7/2017    5   4/11/2017 <--Overlap
Amy Humera  4/13/2017   30  5/12/2017 <--Overlap
```

So after we combine, we get

```
User Drug   RxStartDate DaySupply   RxEndDate
Amy Humera  2/12/2017   7   2/18/2017
Amy Humera  2/28/2017   10  3/9/2017 <-- Combined from above, new overlap
Amy Humera  3/8/2017    2   3/9/2017 <-- Now this overlaps with above
Amy Humera  3/10/2017   7   3/16/2017
Amy Humera  3/17/2017   72  5/27/2017

User Drug   RxStartDate DaySupply   RxEndDate
Amy Humera  2/12/2017   7   2/18/2017
Amy Humera  2/28/2017   12  3/11/2017 <-- Combined, again, new overlap
Amy Humera  3/10/2017   7   3/16/2017 <-- Now this overlaps with above
Amy Humera  3/17/2017   72  5/27/2017

User Drug   RxStartDate DaySupply   RxEndDate
Amy Humera  2/12/2017   7   2/18/2017
Amy Humera  2/28/2017   19  3/18/2017 <-- Combined, again, new overlap
Amy Humera  3/17/2017   72  5/27/2017 <-- Now this overlaps with above

User Drug   RxStartDate DaySupply   RxEndDate
Amy Humera  2/12/2017   7   2/18/2017
Amy Humera  2/28/2017   91  5/29/2017
There is no more overlap…finished!
```

Is there a way to do this automatically in a loop or something...any ideas?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @rosie chi: Don't you think this question should be [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) with [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309501/looping-updates-better-way-to-do-this)? I keep testing these solutions but seems to me that only recursion could do the job. And in that post I already showed one implementation so others should see that also before coding the same thing.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó: I think that is a great idea!  I have read the 'merged' link you indicated, but it looks like that I am unable to do the merge, only moderators.  Is it possible for you to potentially post your answer from that post over here?

Comment: @aduguid:  I guess this is important...I'm using SQL Server 2008.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I copied my answer here. Also marked the other question to be closed (nothing added there since).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution can only be implemented by recursion, as there should be a loop that calculates the accumulated DaySupply and I see no way of doing that with any non-recursive lookups. You can do this with recursive [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - and according to the official doc, it is available starting with SQL Server 2008.
A possible implementation (I added some test data to challenge it):

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    [User] VARCHAR(100),
    Drug VARCHAR(100),
    RxStartDate DATE,
    DaySupply INT,
    RxEndDate DATE
)

INSERT @test
VALUES
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '2/12/2017', '7', '2/18/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '2/28/2017', '5', '3/4/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/3/2017', '5', '3/7/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/8/2017', '2', '3/9/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/10/2017', '7', '3/16/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/17/2017', '30', '4/15/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/22/2017', '2', '3/23/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/24/2017', '2', '3/25/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '3/31/2017', '3', '4/2/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '4/7/2017', '5', '4/11/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Humera', '4/13/2017', '30', '5/12/2017'),

    ('Amy', 'Other', '3/24/2017', '7', '3/30/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Other', '3/31/2017', '3', '4/2/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Other', '4/7/2017', '5', '4/11/2017'),
    ('Amy', 'Other', '4/13/2017', '30', '5/12/2017'),

    ('Joe', 'Humera', '3/24/2017', '8', '3/31/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Humera', '3/31/2017', '3', '4/2/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Humera', '4/12/2017', '5', '4/16/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Humera', '4/23/2017', '30', '5/22/2017'),

    ('Joe', 'Other', '3/24/2017', '60', '5/23/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Other', '3/31/2017', '3', '4/2/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Other', '4/7/2017', '5', '4/11/2017'),
    ('Joe', 'Other', '4/13/2017', '30', '5/12/2017')



-- You can comment this out, it is just to show progress:
SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY [User], Drug, RxStartDate



DECLARE @test_2 TABLE (
    [User] VARCHAR(100),
    Drug VARCHAR(100),
    RxStartDate_base DATE,
    DaySupplyCumulative INT
)

;WITH CTE_RxEndDateExtended as (
    SELECT [User], Drug, RxStartDate, DaySupply, DaySupply as DaySupplyCumulative, RxStartDate as RxStartDate_base, RxStartDate as RxStartDateExtended, dateadd (dd, DaySupply, RxStartDate) as RxEndDateExtended
    FROM @test
    -- WHERE [User] = 'Amy' and Drug = 'Humera' and RxStartDate = '2/28/2017'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.[User], t.Drug, t.RxStartDate, t.DaySupply, c.DaySupplyCumulative + t.DaySupply as DaySupplyCumulative, c.RxStartDate_base, t.RxStartDate as RxStartDateExtended, dateadd (dd, t.DaySupply, c.RxEndDateExtended) as RxEndDateExtended
    FROM CTE_RxEndDateExtended as c INNER JOIN @test as t
        on c.[User] = t.[User] and c.Drug = t.Drug
            and c.RxEndDateExtended >= t.RxStartDate and c.RxStartDateExtended < t.RxStartDate
)
INSERT @test_2
SELECT [User], Drug, RxStartDate_base, MAX (DaySupplyCumulative) as DaySupplyCumulative -- comment this out and use this for debugging: SELECT *
FROM CTE_RxEndDateExtended
GROUP BY [User], Drug, RxStartDate_base -- comment this out for debugging
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- comment this out and use this for debugging (to avoid infinite loops): OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)



-- You can comment this out, it is just to show progress:
SELECT * FROM @test_2
ORDER BY [User], Drug, RxStartDate_base -- comment this out and use this for debugging: ORDER BY [User], Drug, RxStartDate_base, RxStartDate, DaySupplyCumulative



SELECT base.*, dateadd (dd, base.DaySupplyCumulative - 1, base.RxStartDate_base) as RxEndDateCumulative
FROM @test_2 as base LEFT OUTER JOIN @test_2 as filter
    on base.[User] = filter.[User] and base.Drug = filter.Drug
        and base.RxStartDate_base > filter.RxStartDate_base
        and dateadd (dd, base.DaySupplyCumulative, base.RxStartDate_base) <= dateadd (dd, filter.DaySupplyCumulative, filter.RxStartDate_base)
WHERE filter.[User] IS NULL
ORDER BY [User], Drug, RxStartDate_base
```

Maybe you need to optimize it by simplifying the logic. But be careful not to make an infinite loop. When debugging use OPTION (MAXRECURSION *N*) with *N* other than zero.

PS.: this one works also if I add 'Amy', 'Humera', '2/15/2017', '11', '2/25/2017', with which I was criticizing the other solutions... I am curious if it works as you expect - please test!

Comment: WaHoo! This solution worked for me with SQL Server 2008.  I made a tiny change...add a '=' after the last '<' when comparing the 2 dateadds, as it was showing weird results without it.  I am unable to edit the code itself as the change is too minute (only changes of 6 characters or above can be done).  Anyways, thank you very much for your assistance all the way from the other post to this one!

Comment: Do you mean this line should have <=: and dateadd (dd, base.DaySupplyCumulative, base.RxStartDate_base) < dateadd (dd, filter.DaySupplyCumulative, filter.RxStartDate_base) ?

Comment: That is a nice correction, I updated the post. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify where a group starts, using `not exists`.  Then do a cumulative sum to assign a group . . . and aggregate.  The following assumes a unique id, which is sort of needed to handle duplicates:

```
select [user], drug, grp, sum(daysupply), min(RxStartDate), max(RxEndDate)
    from (select t.*, sum(flg) over (partition by [user], drug order by RxStartDate) as grp
          from (select t.*,
                       (case when exists (select 1
                                          from @test t2
                                          where t2.[user] = t.[user] and t2.drug = t.drug and
                                                t2.RxStartDate < t.RxStartDate and
                                                t2.RxEndDate >= dateadd(day, -1, t.RxStartDate)
                                         )
                             then 0 else 1
                        end) as flg
                from @test t
               ) t
          ) t
    group by [user], drug, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...I'm getting an error code of: Incorrect syntax near 'order' and Incorrect syntax near 't' when I run the code... I feel like this is so close, would you mind helping me check what is going on?  Your code is hard to wrap my head around :-)

Comment: Ok, so I've removed the ORDER BY in the window function since I'm not sure that it is necessary (maybe it is?) and now the error is :Incorrect syntax near 'grp' after the GROUP BY

Comment: Also, I have structured my data in a way where the prescriptions are already ordered by the drug, then the RxStartDate, and I have already removed any duplicates, so that the same drug should never have the same RxStartDate

Comment: @rosiechi . . . The `order by` is quite critical to the window function.  Otherwise, `grp` is not set correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I just read up on the order by part, and figured out that my server does not support this function, which is why I was getting the error!

Comment: I like the approach of assigning groups to rows. However, this solution happens to work with the sample data, but if I add 'Amy', 'Humera', '2/15/2017', '11', '2/25/2017', I don't get the correct result of having only one consecutive interval. It says I have 2 intervals, one 18 days and one 91 days. If you add 18-1 days to 2/12/2017 it becomes 3/1/2017 and that is a new overlap with 2/28/2017. I think a non-recursive approach won't work in the general case as something needs to keep track of the accumulated overlapping days.

Answer (score 0):

I used a [CTE Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to perform the grouping. Since some of the days don't technically overlap, I created an alternate end date `[RxEndDate_ALT]` by adding 1 to the `[RxEndDate]` in the `source_data`. Then I was able to group the dates using `NOT EXISTS` in `source_data_grouped`. After that, I join back to the `source_data_raw` to `SUM` the `[DaySupply]`.

---

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

---

#### SQL

```
WITH 
source_data_raw
AS 
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 7, CAST('12-Feb-2017' AS DATE), CAST('18-Feb-2017' AS DATE))
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 5, '28-Feb-2017', '04-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 5, '03-Mar-2017', '07-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 2, '08-Mar-2017', '09-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 7, '10-Mar-2017', '16-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 30, '17-Mar-2017', '15-Apr-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 2, '22-Mar-2017', '23-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 2, '24-Mar-2017', '25-Mar-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 3, '31-Mar-2017', '15-Apr-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 5, '07-Apr-2017', '16-Apr-2017')
    , ( 'Amy', 'Humera', 30, '13-Apr-2017', '27-May-2017')
    ) tbl ([User], [Drug], [DaySupply], [RxStartDate], [RxEndDate]) 
) 
, 
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT 
          sdr.[User]
        , sdr.[Drug]
        , sdr.[RxStartDate]
        , sdr.[RxEndDate]
        , [RxEndDate_ALT] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, sdr.[RxEndDate])
    FROM 
        source_data_raw AS sdr
)
, 
source_data_grouped
AS
(
    SELECT 
          s1.[User]
        , s1.[Drug]
        , s1.[RxStartDate]
        , [RxEndDate] = MIN(t1.[RxEndDate]) 
    FROM 
        source_data AS s1 
        INNER JOIN source_data AS t1 ON s1.[User] = t1.[User] AND s1.[Drug] = t1.[Drug] AND s1.[RxStartDate] <= t1.[RxEndDate_ALT]
            AND NOT EXISTS 
                (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM source_data AS t2
                    WHERE 
                        1=1
                        AND t1.[User] = t2.[User]
                        AND t1.[Drug] = t2.[Drug]
                        AND t1.[RxEndDate_ALT] >= t2.[RxStartDate]
                        AND t1.[RxEndDate_ALT] < t2.[RxEndDate_ALT]
                ) 
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM source_data AS s2
            WHERE 
                1=1
                AND s1.[User] = s2.[User]
                AND s1.[Drug] = s2.[Drug]
                AND s1.[RxStartDate] > s2.[RxStartDate]
                AND s1.[RxStartDate] <= s2.[RxEndDate_ALT]
        )
    GROUP BY 
          s1.[User]
        , s1.[Drug]
        , s1.[RxStartDate]
)
SELECT 
      sdg.[User]
    , sdg.[Drug]
    , [DaySupply] = SUM(sdr.[DaySupply])
    , sdg.[RxStartDate]
    , sdg.[RxEndDate]
FROM 
    source_data_grouped AS sdg
    INNER JOIN source_data_raw AS sdr ON sdr.[RxStartDate] BETWEEN sdg.[RxStartDate] AND sdg.[RxEndDate]
GROUP BY 
      sdg.[User]
    , sdg.[Drug]
    , sdg.[RxStartDate]
    , sdg.[RxEndDate]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to return the correct daysupply. And this one has the same issue as Gordon Linoff's: this solution happens to work with the sample data, but if I add 'Amy', 'Humera', '2/15/2017', '11', '2/25/2017', I don't get the correct result of having only one consecutive interval. It says I have 2 intervals, one 18 days and one 91 days. If you add 18-1 days to 2/12/2017 it becomes 3/1/2017 and that is a new overlap with 2/28/2017. I think a non-recursive approach won't work in the general case as something needs to keep track of the accumulated overlapping days.